# How to speed up DatetimeIndex processing?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, datetimeindex

I have a large pandas DataFrame (around 1050000 entries). One of the columns is of type `datetime`. I want to extract year, month and weekday. The problem is that the code shown below is extremely slow:

```
df['Year'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).year
df['Month'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).month
df['Weekday'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).weekday
```

Update:

The data looks like this:

```
      Id  DayOfWeek       Date
0      1          5 2015-07-31   
1      2          4 2015-07-30   
2      3          3 2015-07-29   
3      4          2 2015-07-28  
4      5          1 2015-07-27
```

If I do this way:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=[2])

df['Year'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).year
df['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).month
df['Weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']).weekday
```

then the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'year'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You state that your column is already of the datetime64 type. In that case you can simply use the [`.dt` accessor](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html#dt-accessor) to expose the methods and attributes associated with the datetime values in the column:

```
df['Year'] = df.Date.dt.year
```

This will be much quicker than writing `pd.DatetimeIndex(df.Date).year` which creates a whole new index object first.

Comment: It says AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: Ah - then you don't have a column with the datetime64 dtype after all. You need to convert the column; you can use `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` as suggested in qmorgan's answer.

Comment: Then it says ValueError: New date column already in dict Date... I am reading csv this way: df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=dtypestrain), where dtypestrain = { 'Id': int,
                'DayOfWeek': int,
                'Date': dt.datetime}

Comment: And also AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parsedDate'

Comment: It's much easier just to let `read_csv` infer the column dtypes. Try using `pd.read_csv("data.csv", parse_dates=[2])` to have the function parse the datetime values when it reads the data.

Comment: Could you please see my update? I posted the code and the problem.

Comment: @KlausosKlausos: you forgot the `.dt` accessor: use `.dt.year`. Also you may want avoid calling `pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])` each time - just to it once and then get each attribute in turn.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you may be parsing the dates each time rather than all at once. Also, using the `to_datetime()` method may be faster.

Try

```
df['parsedDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df['Year'] = pd.parsedDate.year
df['Month'] = pd.parsedDate.month
df['Weekday'] = pd.parsedDate.weekday
```

Comment: It says ValueError: New date column already in dict Date... I am reading csv this way: df = pd.read_csv("data.csv", dtype=dtypestrain), where dtypestrain = { 'Id': int, 'DayOfWeek': int, 'Date': dt.datetime}

Comment: Or AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'parsedDate'